# Mailer function Ruby on Rails issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying compile a function with user id, but not working out. Tried different ways but getting nil as response in my production logs.

Any help is welcome

```
def function(user)
    attachments['example.pdf'] = File.read("public/#{@user.id}_file.pdf")
    @user = user
    mail :subject => 'example', to: user.email, from: 'invoice@domain.com',  track_opens: true
end
```

---

Log:

> D, [2019-07-08T10:51:56.838759 #64733] DEBUG -- :
>   TestMailer#send_sub_month: processed outbound mail in 1.1ms I,
>   [2019-07-08T10:51:56.839003 #64733]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms) F,
>   [2019-07-08T10:51:56.839615 #64733] FATAL -- :    F,
>   [2019-07-08T10:51:56.839671 #64733] FATAL -- : NoMethodError
>   (undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass): F,
>   [2019-07-08T10:51:56.839710 #64733] FATAL -- :    F,
>   [2019-07-08T10:51:56.839750 #64733] FATAL -- :
>   app/mailers/test_mailer.rb:90:in `send_sub_month'

Answer (score 0):

The logs say that you are trying to access the `id`  attribute of an empty object.

```rb
NoMethodError (undefined method id' for nil:NilClass)
```

You have a string where the user is used is higher than the string where the user is defined

Try this:

```rb
def function(user)
  @user = user

  attachments['example.pdf'] = File.read("public/#{@user.id}_file.pdf")

  mail :subject => 'example', to: user.email, from: 'invoice@domain.com', track_opens: true
end
```

**Updated.**

If you pass a user as an argument to a function, then it makes no sense to create a variable for it.

```rb
def function(user)
  attachments['example.pdf'] = File.read("public/#{user.id}_file.pdf")

  mail :subject => 'example', to: user.email, from: 'invoice@domain.com', track_opens: true
end
```